# WPF WebBrowser.InvokeScript() Keeps Loading Old Script

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, invokescript

I have a very simple JavaScript file named as MyJava.htm as shown below:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowMe(message)
    {
        var n = message.length;
        var s = a.toString();
        alert("total length = " + s);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body style='background-color:transparent'>
    <P>Empty</P>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, there is an error in the code ('a' is undefined). I saved the file into my local machine's web server folder, which is c:\inetpub\wwwroot.

When I first run it using WPF WebBrowser control (this) as follows:

```
JavascriptInterface jint = new JavascriptInterface(mainWindow);
this.myBrowser.ObjectForScripting = jint;
this.myBrowser.Source = new Uri( @"http://127.0.0.1/myJava.htm");
this.myBrowser.InvokeScript("ShowMe", "Hello");
```

where mainWindow is a dialog. I'll get the error message saying 'a' is undefined.

Then, I went into the file MyJava.htm and corrected it (replacing variable 'a' with 'n'); saved the file; reran the WPF application.

I still get the 'a' is undefined error.

If I rename the file and change the URL accordingly, then everything works.

Apparently, the old script was being loaded even I've altered the content of the file.

How do I resolve this? How can I tell WPF (or whoever) to load the new contents from the URL?

Comment: Do you restart your WPF program and it loads the whole thing again or do you have some code after this that is supposed to load the new file?

Comment: I reran the program from beginning.